# get count of subjects with at least one record in posts table

Tags: mysql, php

I have two tables: `posts` and `subjects`.

`posts` may have `subjects`, but not all `subjects` may have been assigned to some `posts`. Now I want to count only those `subjects` with at least one `post` related to them.

subject columns are: `id`, `name`
posts columns are: `id`, `title`, `subject_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly simple :

```
select distinct subject.* from subject inner join post on subject.id = post.subject_id
```

To get only count :

```
select count(distinct subject.id) as subject_count from subject inner join post on subject.id = post.subject_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select count(*) from subjects where exists (select 1 from posts where subjects.id = posts.subject_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from subject s inner join posts p on s.id=p.subject_id
```